# Exponential integral approximation

Tags: integration, statistics, special-functions, exponential-function, statistical-inference

I have an equation that contain exponential integral of the form:

$$ \begin{equation}
E_k\left(\frac{a+b ~x}{c}\right)
\end{equation} $$

Where $k\geq 0$ ($k=0,1,2,...$), $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants, and $x>0$.

How to get the approximation of the above expression?

Comment: What is $Ei(k,\frac{a+b ~x}{c})$?. Do you mean $E_k(\frac{a+b ~x}{c})$? And what approximation, for large $x$, small $c$ or what?

Comment: Yes its 
$$ \begin{equation}
E_k(\frac{a+b ~x}{c})
\end{equation} $$

which gives the exponential integral function, please see this for more detail: reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExpIntegralEi.html Yes, usually the approximation is for large x. however the above form of expression is not tractable, and can't be solved, I want to know if there is any approximation that I can eliminate this function.

Comment: Besides the usual continued fraction from Abramowitz and Stegun 5.1.22
$$
E_n(x) = e^{-x} \left(
\frac{1}{x+} \; \frac{n}{1+} \; \frac{1}{x+} \; \frac{n+1}{1+} \; \frac{2}{x+}  \ldots \right)
$$
you may exploit the connection of the  generalized exponential integrals $E_p(x)$ with the incomplete Gamma functions
$$
E_p(x) = x^{p-1} \Gamma(1-p,x) = x^{p-1} Q(1-p,x)\: \Gamma(1-p).
$$
And for the $E_p$ there are powerful asymptotic expansions given in the NIST Handbook http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.20

Comment: @gammatester that was very useful, especially the links. but I don't understand what is meant by `x+` , and `1+` , ..
COULD YOU PLEASE TELL ME WHAT IS THAT MEAN?

Comment: The notations `x+` and `1+` are parts of a compact standard type-set form for continued fractions, cf. http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19#vii. Here is a more space-consuming form:
\begin{equation}
E_n(x) = \cfrac{e^{-x}}{
    x + \cfrac{n}{
    1 + \cfrac{1}{
    x + \cfrac{n+1}{
    1 + \cfrac{2}{
    x + \cdots}
}}}}
\end{equation}

Comment: @gammatester your answers are always constructive.

Can I use this approximation:
$$ \begin{equation}
E_n\left({x}\right)
 = (\frac{e^{-x}}{x+n}) \end{equation} $$
Also what happen if the Exponential Integral Function is like this:
$$ \begin{equation}
E_{n+1}
\left({x}\right)\end{equation} $$

Comment: Yes you can use this as an approximation, it actually is the first term of the large $n$ approximation from Abramowitz and Stegun 5.1.52. The large $x$ approximation in 5.1.51 starts
$$E_n(x) \sim \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\left(1-\frac{n}{x} + \frac{n(n+1)}{x^2} \pm \dots\right),$$ and it may be better for your case (they are equivalent to first order).
For your second question: You can substitute $n+1$ for $n$ in all terms.