# How to approximate an Exponential integral with upper boundary

Tags: integration, exponential-function, approximation

I am trying to approximate an exponential integral which has an upper boundary that is not infinite. The integral I am trying to solve is:

$\int_{1}^{x_1} \frac{exp(-Ax)}{x^2} dx$

If the upper limit is $\infty$ this can be expressed as en exponential integral, however how could I solve this integral with the finite limit of $x_1$?

*Edit:* the limits of the variables are:
$x_1 > 1$ and $A>0$

Comment: Order of magnitude of $A$ and $x_1$? I guess that $x_1>1$ and $A>0$ (this should be stated). What did you get by integration by parts?

Comment: That guess is indeed correct. I added it to the question. I tried integration by parts. First integration you are left with an exponential integral of the first order (which still has the upper boundary problem) and a continued integration by parts gives something of the form: $\int log(x) exp(-Ax)$ which does not help me to see how to solve this.

Comment: Maybe you want to integrate $e^{-Ax}$ and differentiate $\frac{1}{x^2}$ (not the opposite), especially if $A$ is large. You may iterate this approach a couple of times, then use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to approximate the last integral you get.

Comment: And how would you know that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality approximates the integral? (and thus why would you even integrate by parts before you use this approximation?)

Comment: In terms of the exponential integral function,
$$\int_1^{x_1} \frac {e^{-A x}} {x^2} dx =
A \operatorname{Ei}(-A) - A \operatorname{Ei}(-A x_1) +
 e^{-A} - \frac {e^{-A x_1}} {x_1}.$$
How do you decide what will be a good approximation for this? Do you need an estimate for large $A$ and fixed $x_1$, or for large $x_1$ and fixed $A$, or for some more complex conditions?

In other words, to be able to estimate the approximation error as $O(f(x))$, one needs to specify either a limiting value of $x$ or a set of values of $x$ over which the big $O$ estimate should hold.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I am not familliar with making estimates of the error, how would I estimate O?

Comment: So far we only have an exact formula in terms of the exponential integral function $\operatorname {Ei}$, there is no error term. Suppose I approximate the exact value with $e^{-A}/A$. This might be a good upper boundary for large $A$ and useless for small $A$. So thus far I think the question is too vague.

Btw, I'm not the author of the post, so I don't automatically see the replies in my inbox. Add @username somewhere in the comment to make sure that person gets a notification.

Comment: @Maxim Ok, so if I understand it correctly we only need to estimate $Ei$? Would it in general be OK to (under the assumption that we do not have an complex argument) to change the expression to: $A E_2(-A) - A E_2(-Ax_1) + e^{-A} - \frac{e^{-A x_1}}{x_1}$ and a then estimate it with an continued fraction found  [here][1]? This does not include a range of validity for both $A$ and $x_1$. And thus effectively solving my question by the expression for the exponential integral function you provided.


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529812/exponential-integral-approximation

Comment: For $A>0$, $\operatorname{Ei}(-A) = -E_1(A)$. Then yes, we can use the continued fraction expansion for $E_1(A)$.